# installing virtualenvwrapper causes untested argparse to be installed

Tags: argparse, virtualenvwrapper, python-3.5

I have installed `virtualenvwrapper` in a 3.5.0b1 virtualenv, called `setupenv`, to be able to generate new python 3.5 test environments easily.

Looking over the list of installed packages, I did see `argparse` version 1.3.0 installed. This (latest) version of `argparse` [has not been tested with 3.5](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/argparse/1.3.0).

Is this dangerous?

As far as I know 3.2+ comes with its own `argparse`. Could this install break other packages relying on `argparse`? Why is this installed at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably not dangerous. If you run:

```
python3.5 -c "import argparse; print(argparse.__file__)"
```

, you can see that the `arparse.py` installed with the interpreter takes precedence over the superfluously installed `argparse` package.

A bit of digging (or using the [pipdeptree](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pipdeptree) package) will show you that [`stevedore`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/stevedore/1.5.0) is dependent on `argparse`. This is just sloppy programming (or disregard of possible bandwidth issues). 
In a package's `setup.py` you can easily test if you are running python < 2.7 or 3.0 <= python < 3.2 and only install `argparse` for those cases.

I would just de-install `argparse` from your `setupenv` virtualenv (`pip uninstall argparse -y`), virtualenvwrapper is not  affected by the removal in my experience.

---

This is actually a bug in `stevedore`, it uses the `pbr` package and that supports specification of the python version using [environment markers](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/pbr/#environment-markers)
but `stevedore` is not using that. The irony is that the example for this in `pbr` **is** with `argparse`, by specifying in the `requirements.txt`:

```
argparse; python=='2.6'
```

A [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-stevedore/+bug/1462741) against `stevedore` was filed, but although the fix was trivial, it was not implemented for several releases. Finally the issue was 
set to won't fix, probably because dropped support for 2.6 removed the
need for argparse altogether.